# Why does my Nintendo 64 randomly reset?

Tags: nintendo-64

I have an N64 that will reset/restart back to the Nintendo 64 logo as if power cycling at random. It isn't a set amount of time into the game, or based on a button combination, but it always resets the same across various games. Sometimes the N64 will reset repeatedly at the logo screen. What are the possible reasons for this happening, and how can I stop it? Is it possible to diagnose or repair the issue myself? I'm using standard controllers and cables, no mods, and the little red/black expansion pack.

Comment: Just curious if any of your buttons are sticky on the controller? Meaning do they stay down at times even though you are no longer pressing them. There is a button combination that can be pressed on a controller to reset the entire system, I don't remember what it was but I can recall doing it on occasion when I would be playing a game with my brother and he would start cheating.

Comment: @Ravekner: Not to my knowledge, but it would also be tough to have L+R+Start stuck or depressed at once. I'm relatively sure it'd reset if I walked away from it for long enough. I get the feeling it has to do with overheating, but I don't have it on for ten minutes before it goes haywire and I know others have had similar issues, so I don't know what my symptoms or common fixes are.

Comment: My friend's NES does this too.

Answer (score 10):

A simple [google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=n64+random+reset) reveals many potential explanations, but it's a common problem with older North American N64s and darn near impossible to accurately diagnose without trying almost everything. The hardware is notoriously finicky, now quite old, and generally difficult to troubleshoot.

Common explanations include overheating, dirt, and hardware failure.

Prevalent approaches to identifying/resolving this generally go like this:

- Remove expansion pack and test for the issue. If this solves things, it looks like expansion pack has failed. It could be the connector pins or internal hardware or even just dirt on the pins, although that's less likely. Inspect and clean with isopropyl rubbing alcohol on a q-tip and dry with a q-tip as well - do not blow on or use compressed air. You may have to replace it.
- Check if the reset button on the console is stuck down, even a little as that's been know to happen with this hardware. If it is slightly depressed, try to *very carefully* lift the button with a small flat tool such as a knife or flat-headed screwdriver. Test for the issue. If this fixes things, then keep an eye on the reset button - you might even consider jerry-rigging a way to prop the button up if the issue resumes.
- Clean the pins and connectors of the console and games with isopropyl rubbing alcohol on q-tips. DO NOT BLOW ON OR USE COMPRESSED AIR - it's even in the manual that this can damage the system or games. After sufficiently cleaned and dried (again, with q-tips), test for the issue. If this fixes the issue, try to keep the system and area around it cleaner.
- It doesn't matter if hardware is first party or original or whatever - all hardware eventually fails, but some are sooner than others. The most likely failure that is easy to diagnose is the power adapter fusing. The only way I know to test the adapter is to swap another adapter in and see if it does the trick.
- Everything else involves opening up the system and poking around. Cleaning as described above any areas which are visibly dirty or dusty. TAKE EXTREME CARE WHEN MUCKING ABOUT INSIDE THE SYSTEM. The hardware of this device is very touchy and a wrong move can make the situation much worse. The most I'll recommend is a visual inspection to look for anything amiss, especially around the reset button housing and beyond that, I can't even find clear directions about where to start trying to fix this.
- The only step remaining is professional repair or simply replacement. This issue is mostly prevalent in the first generations of N64 in North America and if that's the version you have, it might be more worth your while to replace the console outright. Trying to get it repaired anymore is likely not going to be cheap or easy so I'd recommend replacement of the console itself regardless at this point.

Comment: While this is a reasonably nice answer, I don't like that after offering a few ideas it says "Everything else involves opening up the system...". This false; for example in my case simply securing the power adapter solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I got the exact same problem. It's overheating, the base of the system suffocates when it's over any surface (except the anti thermal ones I guess) because there's no decent airflow.

The solution is very simple and you don't need to tear it apart or buy a new one. I found that you just need to get it off the ground with the help of some supports. Try to find some cylinders or any object that can make the N64 stand on top of them like the Parthenon of Athens (in my case I used those Wii U supports that comes with the black one). The airflow will then function properly and the resetting will stop.

Hope this helps ;)

[image]

Comment: If the problem persists try stick, in a non damaging way, the power supply to the console. The weight of the power supply tends to provoke a false contact.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem with my system, using several different expansion paks and AC adapters. I'd turn it on and it would last long enough for "Nintendo" to appear on the screen, then it would reset over and over. Sometimes it would give me false hope, waiting until I got to a menu screen before it would reset. After taking the consoles, expansion paks, and games apart and cleaning the contact points with copper cleaner and alcohol, the issue was still there. I read somewhere that the issue could be from a broken solder point at the power source, so i soldered one that looked like it may have come loose a bit. Didn't help. **I was about to trash the stupid console when I looked at the part where the AC adapter actually connects to the console and noticed that the pins were black and tarnished. I unplugged everything, then I proceeded to swab some copper cleaner into the holes on the AC adapter and worked it into and out of the connection at the back of the N64 a few dozen times, then cleaned the excess off and did the same thing with alcohol and let it dry. This completely fixed my issue!** I've been all over forums looking for solutions and haven't seen this one yet. Check your power connection for corrosion if the other fixes aren't working. It took me an afternoon to figure out, but hopefully this will help some people in the future!

Answer (score 3):

According to at least two of the users on [this thread](http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=8&threadid=33302), it wasn't any of the things mentioned in skovacs1's post but, instead, a loose-fitting power supply connector.

The solution that worked for them (photos included on the thread) was to jam folded up paper pieces of paper in under the power supply and then apply some tape at the top to ensure it made the most snug connection possible between the N64- and PSU-side connectors.

...but given how easily paper would burst into flame (compared to a wooden tabletop) if the internals of the PSU failed and melted through the plastic housing, exposing the wiring, you'll want something non-flammable.

Comment: Unfortunately sticking paper into a power connector creates a fire hazard; better would be to use something non-flammable.

Comment: :nod: I'll be poking around my DIY supplies to look for something thin and springy but non-flammable when I try it. (Given how far removed it is from the actual electrical contacts, I might try using a paperclip or strip of sheet metal, folded into a hook at the tip so it can't go in further)

Comment: This seems to be a working solution to me, though I am a bit worried about the fire (used paper), but it's only a risk while you're playing, right? No chance it breaks out in the middle of the night when I'm sleeping?

Comment: Unbelievably this worked - just be sure to use something inflammable - I used a bit of thin plastic folded over until it was thick enough to work

Answer (score 2):

This guy apparently has found a solution: a bit in the PSU (that block you connect to the console) has some loose part in it:

I have taken my N64 PSU out for inspection, the bit that connects to the console is very loose on mine, and I do suffer from the reset problem. I'm going to open it, and try the fix in this video to see if that works.

Edit 1: It appears the part that connects to the console (top left in the video) is not supposed to come loose from the rest: it looks like it is broken off. Not surprising, as the prongs that connect it to the main board are tiny. I have used some non conductive epoxy to glue the part back in place, and some non conductive tape to hold it all together even better. Half an hour of Diddy Kong Racing, no resets yet. I'm going to try something more taxing like Perfect Dark later.

Edit 2: a few hours of infiltrating the G5 building and Area 51 later,  my N64 has not yet reset. The part of the power supply that actually connects to my N64 (those 6 pins) used to be pretty wobbly. After the epoxy (and some non-conductive tape), it is no longer wobbly, and my N64 no longer resets. If anyone else is reading this, please confirm if this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

My Nintendo 64 used to reset on its own, not with a specific amount of time in between each reset, etc.

Well, to solve that problem, I actually did something very random; unplug the power adapter from the console after each use. You know the big black box that goes behind the console for the power supply? Unplug that.

Worked like a charm for me, doesn't reset any more. It's probably because the electricity made it too hot for the adapter to handle and it went off because of it. Anyway, hope this helps any more out there that needs support with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen in some games that the battery is starting to die. I changed a battery in my super mario 64 it solved the problem while I was playing that game. And hasn't happened since. Now reading these other posts above I will test other item in the console to see if other things have happened.

Comment: Very few Nintendo 64 cartridges contained batteries, using either EEPROM or Flash memory, or outsourcing it to a Controller Pak. Super Mario 64 does **not** contain a battery to be changed. See [Micro-64](http://micro-64.com/database/gamesave.shtml) for the list or DAT-o-MATIC for PCB photos from the North American and European releases. (I've also opened up every one of my own cartridges in order to identify the best orientation to store them in, just in case the battery starts to leak, and I can confirm that SM64 has no battery.)

Answer (score -1):

I've actually seen a Gamecube and a 64 start working properly after their utility power was disconnected and then reconnected.

If unplugging and replugging the utility power adapter doesn't work, then dip a swab in alcohol and clean the jumper/expansion pack's connectors and the socket it plugs into.  The purer the alcohol, the better.  Remember to unplug the machine first.

If this doesn't work, you might need new hardware.

Comment: You should be editing your previous answer, not making another.

Answer (score -2):

Can't guarantee this will work, but unplug the utility power adapter from the back of the console, and then plug it back in.  See if that helps.

Comment: Why would this fix it?

Comment: In theory if the connection was plug was faulty, any vibration in the room (e.g. someone walking about) could break the power connection temporarily, causing the reset. Although I would say getting a replacement lead is generally a better solution than simply re-plugging the wire.